# HIT instance has no attribute 'Title' for HITs returned by boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm using the `boto` library to play around with Amazon MTurk. I want to retrieve some reviewable HITs, and display their properties. For example:

```
hits = self.mturk_conn.get_reviewable_hits(page_size=30, status='Reviewable', sort_by='Expiration', sort_direction='Ascending', page_number=1)

for h in hits:
    print '%s: %s' % (h.HITId, h.Title)
```

I do manage to get `HITId`, but for some reason I cannot get `Title` as I get this error msg:

```
AttributeError: HIT instance has no attribute 'Title'
```

A look at AWS API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITDataStructureArticle.html) suggests that the property should be there. In fact, if I get individual HIT through `get_hit` method of `boto`, `Title` property exists. Any reason why this does not work for the HITs returned by `get_reviewable_hits` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at an example response for the [actual operation that you are calling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetReviewableHITsOperation.html).

While the singular [GetHIT call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetHITOperation.html) returns a full HIT data structure.

As you can see in the [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITDataStructureArticle.html) for the HIT data structure, not all of the attributes are required.

It depends on the API call you make which attributes the HIT response object has. (Confusing, right!?)

In this case you actually have to call `GetReviewableHITs`, then use the HITId returned for `GetHIT` to get a full structure that includes the `Title` attribute.

By the way, instead of using Boto you might use [my Python mTurk API](https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python) which uses the exact names in the API docs :)